# how can I prevent duplicate data from being fetched?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CurrentUser").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("MyOrder");
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            parentModelArrayList =  new ArrayList<>();
            parentModelArrayList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot parentSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = parentSnapshot.getKey();

         ArrayList<MyOrder> childModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
                databaseReference.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ArrayList<MyOrder> childModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : parentSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            MyOrder parentOrder = childSnapshot.getValue(MyOrder.class);
                            parentModelArrayList.add(parentOrder);

                            MyOrder childOrder = childSnapshot.getValue(MyOrder.class);
                            if (!childModelArrayList.contains(childOrder)) {
                                childModelArrayList.add(childOrder);
                            }
                            parentOrder.setChildModelArrayList(childModelArrayList);
                        }
                        ParentAdapter = new OrderHistoryParentRcyAdapter(parentModelArrayList, OrderActivity.this);
                        parentRecyclerView.setAdapter(ParentAdapter);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

when running the code.

When looking at the picture of the app running, you can see that it is fetching the same duplicate data values. I want to solve this problem.

I thought it might be a problem with the execution order in OrderActivity.java, so I tried changing the order, but the parent part representing the date in the app execution picture and the child representing the product picture, product name, and price did not appear at the same time. I tried, but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is causing the problem, but your code is **loading** the data from the database twice.

This line loads all the data under `databaseReference` already:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
```

This gives you a snapshot of all data under `databaseReference`, so you don't have to load child nodes separately.

Knowing this, the code to load data can be simplified to:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        parentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        parentModelArrayList.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot parentSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = parentSnapshot.getKey();

            ArrayList<MyOrder> childModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : parentSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MyOrder parentOrder = childSnapshot.getValue(MyOrder.class);
                parentModelArrayList.add(parentOrder);

                MyOrder childOrder = childSnapshot.getValue(MyOrder.class);
                if (!childModelArrayList.contains(childOrder)) {
                    childModelArrayList.add(childOrder);
                }
                parentOrder.setChildModelArrayList(childModelArrayList);
            }
        }

        ParentAdapter = new OrderHistoryParentRcyAdapter(parentModelArrayList, OrderHistoryActivity.this);
        parentRecyclerView.setAdapter(ParentAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("OrderHistoryActivity", String.valueOf(databaseError.toException()));
    }
});
```